# selectAllChildren calls onselectionchange more than once on iOS real device

Tags: javascript, ios, webview, selection

The app lets users to select text from the content of WKWebView. When users long press on a word  (eg "mountain"), it will automatically select the entire sentence that the word is in.

The following code works fine in simulator, but fails in real device, `onselectionchange` is called again when finger is up from the screen, and the selection back to the previous selected word ("mountain").

According to `Selection` API, the `onselectstart` is a better way to solve this, but it seems to not work on iOS, it's called when a selection is dismissed.

```
    var isTextSelected = false;
    document.onselectionchange = () => {
        let selection = window.getSelection();

        if(selection.type == "Caret" || selection.type == "None") {
            isTextSelected = false;
            return;
        }

        const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
        const word = range.startContainer.wholeText;
        if(word == "") {
           return;
        }

        if(isTextSelected || selection.rangeCount == 0) {
            return;
        }
        isTextSelected = true;

        const nid = range.startContainer.parentNode.parentNode.id
        var element = document.getElementById(nid);
        selection.selectAllChildren(element);
      };
```